# Responsive, horizontal table design

Tags: html, css

I want to show my table like the following, at a certain screen size (with   `@media`):

***Default table view:***

> **(1|1)** (1|2) (1|3)
>
> **(2|1)** (2|2) (2|3)
>
> **(3|1)** (3|2) (3|3)

***My idea for small screens:***

> **(1|1)**
>
> (1|2)
>
> (1|3)
>
> **(2|1)**
>
> (2|2)
>
> (2|3)
>
> **(3|1)**
>
> (3|2)
>
> (3|3)

Do you have any idea how this could be done?
I want the rows to be horizontal aligned.

Comment: do you have any HTML and CSS to share, so we can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible with traditional `table`s but you could use `<div`s.

```css
.col {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .col {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1.1</div><div class="col">1.2</div><div class="col">1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">2.1</div><div class="col">2.2</div><div class="col">2.3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">3.1</div><div class="col">3.2</div><div class="col">3.3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is also another option using css3 tables but has less browser compatibility.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 80px;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .table,
  .tr,
  .td {
    display: block;
  }
  .td {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">1.1</div>
    <div class="td">1.2</div>
    <div class="td">1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">2.1</div>
    <div class="td">2.2</div>
    <div class="td">2.3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">3.1</div>
    <div class="td">3.2</div>
    <div class="td">3.3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need by applying this CSS
**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 400px){ /*Example size*/
       tr {
          display: flex; 
          flex-direction: row;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
       }
}
```

**Example code**
Put the browser in window mode to see the effect ;)

```css
table, th, td {
   border-top: 1px solid black;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
table {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px;
}
th, td {
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
  tr{
     display: flex; 
     flex-direction: row;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  th, td{
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<htlm>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>(1|1)</strong></th><td>(1|2)</td><td>(1|3)</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>(2|1)</strong></th><td>(2|2)</td><td>(2|3)</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>(3|1)</strong></th><td>(3|2)</td><td>(3|3)</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</htlm>
```